# How to access variable update from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I have two methods working simultaneously in a thread and I'm able to access the **access variable and counter variable** from **Loader class into Load class**.

What I want is while the while loop is updating on the **Loader class** to be able to access the update into the **Load class** because I want to use the updated variable.

Is it possible? If so how can I do it?

```
class Loader extends Thread {

    int access = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    public void run() {

        while (access < 5) {
        // System.out.println("Hello " + access);
        System.out.println("counterA is " + counter);

        access++;
        counter++;
    }
}


class Load extends Thread {
    public void run() {

        int me = 0;
        Loader acc = new Loader();
        Loader cou = new Loader();

        int result = acc.access;
        int counterB = cou.counter;

        //cannot get the result and counterB outside a loop
        if (counterB == 3) {
            System.out.println("Access " + result);
            System.out.println("counterB is " + counterB);
        }

       //cannot get the result and counterB inside a loop 
       while (me < 5) {
           if (counterB == 3) {
              System.out.println("Access " + result);
              System.out.println("counterB is " + counterB);
           }

           me++;
        }
    }
}


class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Loader obj = new Loader();
        Load o = new Load();
        obj.start();
        o.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: You'd need the variables that you want to access to be fields, rather than local variables. 
 You'd also need the `Loader` object to have a reference to the `Load` object, so that it can find the field that you want to update.

Comment: This sounds like you need to use the `Observer` pattern to solve this problem. Also, if you need to observe changes in `int` fields, you will need to use `AtomicInteger` instead.

Comment: Can someone give me an example code

Comment: [Observer Pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern). [Atomic Integer](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicinteger.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the fields of the `Loader` class from within the `Load` class,  you would need to have a reference to the `Loader` object in the `Load` class. You can achieve this by passing the `Loader` object into the constructor of the `Load` object or by using a setter etc.

In your code above you created two new `Loader` objects in the `Load` class's `run` method and didn't start either of them so the `access` and `counter` fields of those two `Loader` objects will always be zero. Additionally, I don't know if this is a mistake or not but the `result` and `counterB` variables will not store references to the fields but rather copies of the field values.

Additionally, to prevent [memory consistency errors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html), you should use either [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) or [atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html) (in your case [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)).